# C# OpenCV access structure 'Mat' 's exception problem

Tags: c#, opencv

I trying to get information of an image's pixel, but `System.AccessViolationException` is randomly occurring.

I tried many ways... but could not solve this problem.

How can I solve this problem

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (GetPixelData)
    {
        actualPointX = GetOriginalCoordinate(e.X, pickratio);
        actualPointY = GetOriginalCoordinate(e.Y, pickratio);

        form1.xLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(actualPointX);
        form1.yLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(actualPointY);

        b = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY)[0];
        g = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY)[1];
        r = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY)[2];

        form1.blueLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(b);
        form1.greenLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(g);
        form1.redLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(r);

        form1.blueLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        form1.greenLabel.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        form1.redLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        GetPixelData = false;
        form1.GetPixDataBtn.Enabled = true;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

The exception problem occurs in this code

```
b = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY)[0]; //<-here occurs problem
g = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY)[1];
r = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY)[2];
```

[image]

problem occurring process

1. click 'Get Point Data'
2. click image where you want to get the information of a pixel of pixel
3. the other form shows the information of the pixel ( R,G,B,Coordinate )
4. it works but sometimes don't
5. when it doesn't work, visual studio shows me this (under Image)

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue. If possible can you attach error image?

Comment: @AJAJ can you break out the array access by saving the vector to a variable: var 
 pixel = Oimg.At<Vec3b>(actualPointX, actualPointY);  Might help to know if your indexing is failing or the call to get the pixel.

Comment: @Mike Thanks I will try

Comment: Is `Oimg` non-empty? Is it really a 3-channel image? Are those coordinates within the bounds of that image? | Provide a proper [mcve]. | "it works but sometimes don't" means you still have some work to do -- what are the specific situations when it doesn't work? What do they have in common? How does that differ from the situations when it does work?